# writing a script inside a created division element

Tags: javascript, html, function, file-upload

```
function addkid() {
  if (i <= 2) {
    i++;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<br> Prescription '+i+':<br><input id="uploadFile" class="disableInputField" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />'+'<label class="fileUpload">'+'<input id="uploadBtn" type="file" required class="upload" name="Image'+i+'" />'+'<span class="uploadBtn">Upload</span>'+'</label>'+'  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removekid(this)">';
    document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);

  }
```

This is the javascript function that is used by me to add a file upload option when the "+" is clicked.

```
<div id="kids">

<input id="uploadFile" class="disableInputField" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />


<label class="fileUpload">
    <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" name=Image1 />
    <span class="uploadBtn">Upload</span>
</label>



        <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />(MAX 3)

      </div></td></tr>


                        </div>

            <script>
                 document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function  {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};

            </script>
```

This is the html code that is used to create the 1st file upload option! The function written inside the  code is used to display the file path of the uploaded file! 
Though the  1st javascript code(addkid() function) can be used to create more file upload options using it,it is unable to display the file paths of the uploaded files because i am unable to call the function inside the script tags to the  addkid() function  in the 1st code! how can i call the function inside the script tags to the addkid() function ?

[image]
Though a file has been uploaded to the 2nd file upload option its not displayed
because

```
<script>
                     document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function  {
        document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
    };

                </script>
```

this function is not called

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here:

1) For different upload buttons you have the same ID. It's wrong on so many levels. You should make their ids unique. To achieve that you may do like this:

```
div.innerHTML = '<br> Prescription '+i+':<br><input id="uploadFile-' + i + '" class="disableInputField" and etc...
```

This way every upload button will have id which matches the pattern `uploadFile-N` where `N` - is the index of the upload button.

And this goes also with buttons for upload and delete. You should make them unique ids too.

2) Your code inside the HTML script doesn't fire because you can't bind an event on the element which doesn't yet exist. All you have to do, is to move your code `document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange ... and etc` to this part of you first javascript code sample:

```
function addkid() {
    if (i <= 2) {
        i++;
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = '<br> Prescription '+i+':<br><input id="uploadFile-' + i + '" class="disableInputField" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />'+'<label class="fileUpload">'+'<input id="uploadBtn-' + i + '" type="file" required class="upload" name="Image'+i+'" />'+'<span class="another-uploadBtn-' + i + '">Upload</span>'+'</label>'+'  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removekid(this)">';
        document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
        //TODO here I inserted your code that binds onchange event
        document.getElementById("uploadBtn-" + i).onchange = function  {
            document.getElementById("uploadFile-"+i).value = this.value;
        };
    }
}
```